# Is there any c++ integer constant x such that x% 1 not equal to 0

Tags: c++

Is there any c++ integer constant that is relatively prime with 1? There isnt one in the set of mathematical integers, but I was wondering if there was such a number for the c++ language.

NaN or INT_MAX or some other #define ed constants maybe?

Comment: This smells strongly of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you provide some information on why you need this?

Comment: NaN is not an integer; it's a floating-point constant. `INT_MAX` is still just an ordinary number and obeys the usual rules, and `#define` can't invent new constants; it can only rename them. There are some interesting quirks in floating-point arithmetic (like NaN), but integers are actually pretty straightforward and do mostly what you'd expect

Comment: There's no such an integral value in the ISO C++. You might get more help if you describe what exactly you're trying to solve is.

Comment: There is no reason to close this.  It's a straightforward question with a straightforward answer that will either be yes or no.

Comment: it might be an xy problem, though I also don't see a reason to close it. Y alone is an ok question, no matter what was the X. XY problems are problematic when Y is unclear or cannot be answered without more information on X, I don't think thats the case here

Comment: no integer like that exists in real life either

Answer (score 7):

No.  You did not use the tag "language-lawyer", so I won't refer to the standard but will instead just look at what typical compilers do.  [Using Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:2,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:2,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:2,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:2),source:%27int+foo(int+x)+%7B%0A++return+x+%25+1%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O1%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), I see that GCC 11.2 compiles the following C++ function to assembly that always just returns 0:

```cpp
int foo(int x) {
    return x % 1;
}
```

Also Clang 13.0.1 does that too.

So the compiler developers have thought about this and determined that there are no integers that satisfy the condition you are looking for.

Comment: fwiw https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#4. OP is basically asking whether there is an `int` `a` such that `(a/1)*1 + 1 == a`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That does assume `a % 1 == 1`, instead it probably should be `(a / 1) * 1 + k == a`, where `k` is a non-`0` `int`

Answer (score 2):

`%` is defined in [expr.mul#4](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#4):

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second.
> If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined.
> For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded; if the quotient a/b is representable in the type of the result, (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a; otherwise, the behavior of both a/b and a%b is undefined.

Your question can be phrased as: Are there integers `a` and `k!=0` such that `(a/1)*1 + k == a`. However, only `0` can be added to `(a/1)*1 == a` to get `a`. In different words, there is no integer `a` such that `(a/1)*1` is not `a`.

No, `a%1 == 0` for any integer `a`.